# Three.js rotating the camera in elliptical shape

Tags: three.js, camera, perspectivecamera

I am trying to get my camera `perspectiveCamera` to rotate around a scene that is elliptical or rectangular in shape. I cant seem to figure out a way to get the camera to automatically zoom out when it hits an edge so that the scene doesn't get cut off.

for visualization purposes I want pretty much [this effect](https://www.aruba.com/us/our-island#Aruba360Map)

I've been trying all day and short of hardcoding positions (which can't be the right solution) I'm falling short.

Comment: Not an answer. Just a thought: try to use `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()` and move your camera along it with mouse movements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy of @prisoner849's with certain issues *fixed* for some definition of fixed.
Thought about just editing that answer but thought I was making too many changes. Happy to take this down if this is inappropriate

1. Fix discontinuity bug
2. Remove dependency on window size
3. Make code handle resize
4. Handle mouse capture

   note: mouse capture doesn't work in an iframe on Chrome as of v69, nor Safari as implemented here. It does work in Firefox. In other words, click on the image, drag *outside the window*. If you're an iframe you'll stop getting events as soon as you drag outside the frame. If you're the top level frame you'll continue to get events event outside the window.

   This has a bunch of issues.

   If you leave the code as is the and you're in an iframe then if the user
   clicks and drags in the iframe, moves the mouse out of the iframe and then
   lets off the mouse button the dragging will be *stuck* to the mouse until
   the user clicks in the frame (the mouseup event never arrives)

   One solution to that is to add a listener to `mouseout` to remove all
   the listeners. The problem with that solution is as soon as the mouse
   touches the edge of the iframe or the window the mouse disconnects from
   dragging which is a horrible UX.

   One other possible solution is to only disconnect the mouse on mouseout
   in an iframe but that still has the issue that as soon as the user 
   goes out of the iframe the mouse disconnects even if they don't let off
   the mouse and end up dragging back into the frame

   checking other sites it appears most sites choose to just let the mouse
   get stuck in dragging mode (embedded google maps shows this behavior as
   does the three.js camera controls as two examples).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(10, 10, -10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25));

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(20, 20, 0x404040, 0x404040));

// island
var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
boxGeo.translate(0, 0.5, 0);
var boxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x909090
});
for (let x = -5; x < 6; x++) {
  for (let y = -3; y < 4; y++) {
    let box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, boxMat);
    box.scale.y = THREE.Math.randInt(1, 3);
    box.position.set(x - 0.5, 0, y - 0.5);
    scene.add(box);
    let edgesGeo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(boxGeo);
    let edges = new THREE.LineSegments(edgesGeo, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xaaaaaa
    }));
    box.add(edges);
  }
}

//path
var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 6, 6),
  new THREE.Vector3(12, 6, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 6, -6),
  new THREE.Vector3(-12, 6, 0)
])
curve.closed = true;

curve.getPoint(0, camera.position);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
var currPoint = 0;
var currPointOnMouseDown = 0;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onCanvasMouseDown, true);

function onCanvasMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, true);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', removeListeners, true);
  mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX;
  currPointOnMouseDown = currPoint;
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var deltaMouseX = event.clientX - mouseXOnMouseDown;
  currPoint = THREE.Math.euclideanModulo(currPointOnMouseDown + deltaMouseX * 0.0005, 1);
}

function removeListeners() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, true);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeListeners, true);
}

render();

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function render() {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  
  curve.getPoint(currPoint, camera.position);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display; block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing :) The purpose of my answer was to show how to use a camera with a curve. I simply took the code for mouse events which more or less moves the camera. I thought it's obvious that the code for mouse events is buggy and it needs fixing from the topic starter. Anyway, thanks one more time :)

Comment: Thank you for the original example! Someone referenced it and didn't know how to handle those issues. Seemed better to deal with it here than on his new question

Comment: True :) I came back here exactly because of the other question and your comment there.

Comment: Thanks to both of you these were really helpful. Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A very rough concept with a curve (code for mouse events is taken from [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html)):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(10, 10, -10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25));

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(20, 20, 0x404040, 0x404040));

// island
var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
boxGeo.translate(0, 0.5, 0);
var boxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x909090
});
for (let x = -5; x < 6; x++) {
  for (let y = -3; y < 4; y++) {
    let box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, boxMat);
    box.scale.y = THREE.Math.randInt(1, 3);
    box.position.set(x - 0.5, 0, y - 0.5);
    scene.add(box);
    let edgesGeo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(boxGeo);
    let edges = new THREE.LineSegments(edgesGeo, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xaaaaaa
    }));
    box.add(edges);
  }
}

//path
var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 6, 6),
  new THREE.Vector3(12, 6, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 6, -6),
  new THREE.Vector3(-12, 6, 0)
])
curve.closed = true;

curve.getPoint(0, camera.position);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var targetRotation = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
var currentPoint = 0;
var currPoint = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
  mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
  targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
  targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
  currPoint = (targetRotation - targetRotationOnMouseDown) * 0.05;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
}

function onDocumentMouseOut(event) {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  curve.getPoint(currPoint, camera.position);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
```